# which one is the largest as n tends to infinity

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[image]

I suppose it is a? I plugged in a specific number to see that. But really not sure how to argue rigorously. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How many of those expressions do you know how to express in terms of $n$?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you are asking which one is the largest between $n^{n+1}$, $n!$ and $\frac{(2n)!}{n!^2}$. Since $\frac{(2n)!}{n!^2}=2^n\cdot\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2k-1}{k}\le 2^n\cdot 2^n=4^n$, the asymptotically largest quantity is $n^{n+1}$.

Comment: ... and other stuff. That's what "basically" was for.

Comment: Thank you very much! In fact, I could write all out explicitly. May I ask how to compare them when N goes to infinit?